# React Datepicker is sending value as string insteadl of YYYY-mm-dd

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

I am using react date picker with react hook form and my code looks like:

```
<Controller
    control={control}
    name="release_date"
    render={({
        field: { onChange, onBlur, value, ref },
    }) => (
        <ReactDatePicker
            onChange={onChange}
            onBlur={onBlur}
            selected={value}
            className="form-control w-full"
            dateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"
        />
    )}
/>
```

It shows as this date on the field `2022-02-15` but its sending data as `Tue Feb 15 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0545 (Nepal Time)` Instead of this how could I send as `yyyy-mm-dd` without using any additional packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you really need it, you can use this away:

create **convert** function:

```
const convert = (selected) => {
    const day = selected.getDate();
    const month =
      selected.getMonth() >= 10
        ? selected.getMonth() + 1
        : `0${selected.getMonth() + 1}`;
    const year = selected.getFullYear();

    return `${year}/${month}/${day}`;
  };
```

change your code:

```
<ReactDatePicker
   onChange={onChange}
   onBlur={onBlur}
   selected={convert(value)}
   className="form-control w-full"
   dateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"
/>
```

Comment: could you please take a look on this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71140998/react-datepicker-default-value-showing-on-the-form-but-still-yup-showing-value

Comment: yes, i will check it.. ^^